# Cutting the YOLOv3 prediction result from the image

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, vision

I have used German Traffic Signs Detection Dataset to train YOLOv3. When I predict, I get results. However, using this code I can't seem to be able to draw bounding boxes around the detection results. Now, that's not my intention. I wanna cut the results out. But I'm not sure how I can turn the YOLOv3 prediction results into coordinates on the image so I can cut it out. Can you help me with this?

```
class BoundBox:
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, objness = None, classes = None):
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.ymax = ymax
        self.objness = objness
        self.classes = classes
        self.label = -1
        self.score = -1
 
    def get_label(self):
        if self.label == -1:
            self.label = np.argmax(self.classes)
 
        return self.label
 
    def get_score(self):
        if self.score == -1:
            self.score = self.classes[self.get_label()]
 
        return self.score
 
def _sigmoid(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))
 
def decode_netout(netout, anchors, obj_thresh, net_h, net_w):
    grid_h, grid_w = netout.shape[:2]
    nb_box = 3
    netout = netout.reshape((grid_h, grid_w, nb_box, -1))
    nb_class = netout.shape[-1] - 5
    boxes = []
    netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])
    netout[..., 4:]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., 4:])
    netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4][..., np.newaxis] * netout[..., 5:]
    netout[..., 5:] *= netout[..., 5:] > obj_thresh
 
    for i in range(grid_h*grid_w):
        row = i / grid_w
        col = i % grid_w
        for b in range(nb_box):
            # 4th element is objectness score
            objectness = netout[int(row)][int(col)][b][4]
            if(objectness.all() <= obj_thresh): continue
            # first 4 elements are x, y, w, and h
            x, y, w, h = netout[int(row)][int(col)][b][:4]
            x = (col + x) / grid_w # center position, unit: image width
            y = (row + y) / grid_h # center position, unit: image height
            w = anchors[2 * b + 0] * np.exp(w) / net_w # unit: image width
            h = anchors[2 * b + 1] * np.exp(h) / net_h # unit: image height
            # last elements are class probabilities
            classes = netout[int(row)][col][b][5:]
            box = BoundBox(x-w/2, y-h/2, x+w/2, y+h/2, objectness, classes)
            boxes.append(box)
    return boxes
 
def correct_yolo_boxes(boxes, image_h, image_w, net_h, net_w):
    new_w, new_h = net_w, net_h
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        x_offset, x_scale = (net_w - new_w)/2./net_w, float(new_w)/net_w
        y_offset, y_scale = (net_h - new_h)/2./net_h, float(new_h)/net_h
        boxes[i].xmin = int((boxes[i].xmin - x_offset) / x_scale * image_w)
        boxes[i].xmax = int((boxes[i].xmax - x_offset) / x_scale * image_w)
        boxes[i].ymin = int((boxes[i].ymin - y_offset) / y_scale * image_h)
        boxes[i].ymax = int((boxes[i].ymax - y_offset) / y_scale * image_h)
 
def _interval_overlap(interval_a, interval_b):
    x1, x2 = interval_a
    x3, x4 = interval_b
    if x3 < x1:
        if x4 < x1:
            return 0
        else:
            return min(x2,x4) - x1
    else:
        if x2 < x3:
             return 0
        else:
            return min(x2,x4) - x3
 
def bbox_iou(box1, box2):
    intersect_w = _interval_overlap([box1.xmin, box1.xmax], [box2.xmin, box2.xmax])
    intersect_h = _interval_overlap([box1.ymin, box1.ymax], [box2.ymin, box2.ymax])
    intersect = intersect_w * intersect_h
    w1, h1 = box1.xmax-box1.xmin, box1.ymax-box1.ymin
    w2, h2 = box2.xmax-box2.xmin, box2.ymax-box2.ymin
    union = w1*h1 + w2*h2 - intersect
    return float(intersect) / union
 
def do_nms(boxes, nms_thresh):
    if len(boxes) > 0:
        nb_class = len(boxes[0].classes)
    else:
        return
    for c in range(nb_class):
        sorted_indices = np.argsort([-box.classes[c] for box in boxes])
        for i in range(len(sorted_indices)):
            index_i = sorted_indices[i]
            if boxes[index_i].classes[c] == 0: continue
            for j in range(i+1, len(sorted_indices)):
                index_j = sorted_indices[j]
                if bbox_iou(boxes[index_i], boxes[index_j]) >= nms_thresh:
                    boxes[index_j].classes[c] = 0
 
# load and prepare an image
def load_image_pixels(filename, shape):
    # load the image to get its shape
    image = load_img(filename)
    width, height = image.size
    # load the image with the required size
    image = load_img(filename, target_size=shape)
    # convert to numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # scale pixel values to [0, 1]
    image = image.astype('float32')
    image /= 255.0
    # add a dimension so that we have one sample
    image = expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image, width, height
 
# get all of the results above a threshold
def get_boxes(boxes, labels, thresh):
    v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores = list(), list(), list()
    # enumerate all boxes
    for box in boxes:
        # enumerate all possible labels
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            # check if the threshold for this label is high enough
            if box.classes[i] > thresh:
                v_boxes.append(box)
                v_labels.append(labels[i])
                v_scores.append(box.classes[i]*100)
                # don't break, many labels may trigger for one box
    return v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores
 
# draw all results
def draw_boxes(filename, v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores):
    # load the image
    data = plt.imread(filename)
    # plot the image
    plt.imshow(data)
    # get the context for drawing boxes
    ax = plt.gca()
    # plot each box
    for i in range(len(v_boxes)):
        box = v_boxes[i]
        # get coordinates
        y1, x1, y2, x2 = box.ymin, box.xmin, box.ymax, box.xmax
        # calculate width and height of the box
        width, height = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
        # create the shape
        rect = Rectangle((x1, y1), width, height, fill=False, color='white')
        # draw the box
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        # draw text and score in top left corner
        label = "%s (%.3f)" % (v_labels[i], v_scores[i])
        plt.text(x1, y1, label, color='white')
    # show the plot
    plt.show()
 
# load yolov3 model
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/model.h5', custom_objects={'yolo_loss': yolo_loss})
# define the expected input shape for the model
input_w, input_h = 416, 416
# define our new photo
photo_filename = '/content/images/00008.jpg'
# load and prepare image
image, image_w, image_h = load_image_pixels(photo_filename, (input_w, input_h))
# make prediction
yhat = model.predict(image)
# summarize the shape of the list of arrays
print([a.shape for a in yhat])
# define the anchors
anchors = [[116,90, 156,198, 373,326], [30,61, 62,45, 59,119], [10,13, 16,30, 33,23]]
# define the probability threshold for detected objects
class_threshold = 0.6
boxes = list()
for i in range(len(yhat)):
    # decode the output of the network
    boxes += decode_netout(yhat[i][0], anchors[i], class_threshold, input_h, input_w)
# correct the sizes of the bounding boxes for the shape of the image
correct_yolo_boxes(boxes, image_h, image_w, input_h, input_w)
# suppress non-maximal boxes
do_nms(boxes, 0.5)
# define the labels
labels = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
# get the details of the detected objects
v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores = get_boxes(boxes, labels, class_threshold)
# summarize what we found
for i in range(len(v_boxes)):
    print(v_labels[i], v_scores[i])
# draw what we found
draw_boxes(photo_filename, v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores)
```

Comment: You have a function called `draw_boxes` – surely you can adapt that to do something else?

Comment: @AKX Here's my problem. It gives negative coordinates (as well as positive). And I can't find a way to crop with negative coordinates. I know `img[x2:x1, y2:y1]` but of course it won't work with negative coordinates. What should I do?

Comment: Ignore the rectangles with negative coordinates?

Comment: @AKX All of them have negative coordinates. In fact I don't think these coordinates are on the image. Is there no way I can decode YOLOv3 output to give me absolute coordinate on the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Yolo format bounding box coordinates into OpenCV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096953/how-to-convert-yolo-format-bounding-box-coordinates-into-opencv-format)