# How to get the coordinates of a bounding box in YOLO?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to get the coordinates of a bounding box in YOLOv4. I followed the accepted answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544471/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-bounding-box-in-yolo-object-detection/55883875).
But, even after editing the image.c file I can not see the BBox coordinates. What am I doing wrong?

I am running YOLO on NVIDIA Jetson Nano on Ubuntu and using the terminal to run the following command:

```
$ ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data \
                      cfg/yolov4-416.cfg \
                      yolov4.weights \
                      -c 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem. the problem is that answer works for darknet [pjreddie](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) model. but i think you are using [AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) model. if it is, you should edit `image_opencv.cpp` file in order to save your bounding box coordinates which is available in src folder. dont forget to re-`make` darknet after change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-ext_output` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **-ext_output**  at the end command. See below:

```
/darknet detector test data/folder_name/image_data.data cfg/yolov4_test.cfg backup/yolov4_train_last.weights data/test_data/test_image.jpg -thresh 0.25 -ext_output
```

Using this command you will get the coordinates in the log along with detected object.